# Word to describe a person who is satisfied/enjoys/feels good seeing their partner excited because of them

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a word to describe a person who is satisfied/enjoys/feels good seeing their partner excited because of them? Like, If I am in a sexual intercourse with a woman and she is showing signs of excitement and pleasure. Therefore if I am a person who feels excited knowing that I am the cause of my partners' pleasure, what am I called?

Maybe if it helps you understand me, I am looking for a word like sapiosexual but with the meaning I described above.

Comment: No. But I am sure the sapiosexuals have been discriminated against and need a name change and a coat of paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are looking for is gratifier which describes one that gratifies.

To gratify as defined by dictionary.com;

> 1. to give pleasure to (a person or persons) by satisfying desires or humoring inclinations or feeling: e.g. Her praise will gratify all who worked so hard to earn it.
> 2. to satisfy; indulge; humor, as one's desires or appetites.